# How to do calculation in a column in pandas and append the result to a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

This is my code

```
def calculate_TP(df):
    countTP=0
    countFP=0
    countTN=0
    countFN=0
    conf_lst=[]
    if df['y']==1 and df['x']==1:
        countTP+=1
    elif df['y']==0 and df['x']==1:
        countFP+=1
    elif df['y']==1 and df['x']==0:
        countFN+=1
    else:
        countTN+=1
```

I have to apply this to a data frame and whatever result I am getting I have to append to a list.

```
conf_lst.append(countTP,countFP,countTN,countFN)
```

How do I do this?
My dataframe is something like this

```
y  x
1  0
0  1
1  1
1  1
```

I have to apply the above function and then change the output as a list.

Comment: Assuming this is a pandas dataframe, change your function to take a row as the input variable (not df). Then use apply to get a series of your results. Then convert the series to a list.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could output the list itself as the `return` of the function:

```
def calculate_TP(df):
    countTP = len(df[(df['y']==1) & (df['x']==1)])
    countFP = len(df[(df['y']==0) & (df['x']==1)])
    countFN = len(df[(df['y']==1) & (df['x']==0)])
    countTN = len(df[(df['y']==0) & (df['x']==0)])
    conf_lst = [countTP,countFP,countFN,countTN]
    return conf_lst
```

Comment: why boolean indexing and not symply sum?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['y','x'])['x'].transform('size')
print(df)
   y  x  count
0  1  0      1
1  0  1      1
2  1  1      2
3  1  1      2
```

if you want a list:

```
df.groupby(['y','x'])['x'].size().unstack(fill_value=0).stack().tolist()

#[0, 1, 1, 2]
```

if I were you I would use a **dict**:

```
df.groupby(['y','x'])['x'].size().unstack(fill_value=0).stack().to_dict()

#{(0, 0): 0, (0, 1): 1, (1, 0): 1, (1, 1): 2}
```

We could also do:

```
c = df['x'].ne(df['y'])
print(df.all(axis=1).sum())
print((~df.any(axis=1)).sum())
print(c.mul(df['x']).sum())
print(c.mul(df['y']).sum())


2
0
1
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your goal, it looks like you're trying to get a confusion matrix as a list. Rather than reinvent the wheel, you could use the [`confusion_matrix`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) function from `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(df.x, df.y).ravel()
conf_list = [tp, fp, tn, fn]

In [9]: conf_list                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[9]: [2, 1, 0, 1]
```